# How to aggregate json fields when using GROUP BY clause in postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

I have the following table structure in my Postgres DB  (v12.0)

```
id | pieces | item_id | material_detail
---|--------|---------|-----------------
1  | 10     | 2       | [{"material_id":1,"pieces":10},{"material_id":2,"pieces":20},{"material_id":3,"pieces":30}]

2  | 20     | 2       | [{"material_id":1,"pieces":40}
3  | 30     | 3       | [{"material_id":1,"pieces":20},{"material_id":3,"pieces":30}
```

I am using GROUP BY query for this records, like below

```
SELECT SUM(PIECES) FROM detail_table GROUP BY item_id HAVING item_id =2
```

Using which I will get the total pieces as 30. But how could I get the count of total pieces from material_detail group by material_id.

I want result something like this

```
 pieces |  material_detail
 -------| ------------------
  30    |  [{"material_id":1,"pieces":50},{"material_id":2,"pieces":20},{"material_id":3,"pieces":30}]
```

As I am from MySQL background, I don't know how to achieve this with JSON fields in Postgres.

**Note:** material_detail column is of JSONB type.

Comment: Could you write the query if the schema was properly normalised, i.e. with `material_detail`s in their own table?

Comment: Please do [not crosspost](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068/157328) also asked here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/268016

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are aggregating on two different levels. I can't think of a solution that wouldn't need two separate aggregation steps. Additionally to aggregate the material information all arrays of the item_id have to be unnested first, before the actual pieces value can be aggregated for each material_id. Then this has to be aggregated back into a JSON array.

```
with pieces as (

  -- the basic aggregation for the "detail pieces"
  select dt.item_id, sum(dt.pieces) as pieces
  from detail_table dt
  where dt.item_id = 2
  group by dt.item_id

), details as (

  -- normalize the material information and aggregate the pieces per material_id
  select dt.item_id, (m.detail -> 'material_id')::int as material_id, sum((m.detail -> 'pieces')::int) as pieces
  from detail_table dt
    cross join lateral jsonb_array_elements(dt.material_detail) as m(detail)
  where dt.item_id in (select item_id from pieces) --<< don't aggregate too much    
  group by dt.item_id, material_id

), material as (

  -- now de-normalize the material aggregation back into a single JSON array
  -- for each item_id
  select item_id, jsonb_agg(to_jsonb(d) - 'item_id') as material_detail
  from details d
  group by item_id

)
-- join both results together
select p.item_id, p.pieces, m.material_detail
from pieces p
  join material m on m.item_id = p.item_id
;
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=be32a71d1cee6719caec06badb088e92)

Comment: what is the use of  cross join lateral here?

Comment: @Sunny: it's required to turn the single JSON into rows. I prefer to write an explicit `cross join lateral` rather then an implicit `from detail_table dt, jsonb_array_elements(...)`

Comment: is it require to include the item_id when normalizing the material info. I guess where and group by clause in that section will return the same records as that of returned in "pieces" and then simply we can jsonb_agg(d) instead of jsonb_agg(to_jsonb(d) - 'item_id') and also I guess join is not required. between pieces and material in the final query.

Comment: If you ever want to do that for more then one item_id, then yes it's required.